# How to define the order when sorting a string enum

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the following enum:

```
public enum TestEnum: String {
    case Day = "Day"
    case Week = "Week"
    case Month = "Month"
}
```

This enum is stored in `Core Data` as a `String`. I want to sort my values based on this my enum in the following order:

- Day
- Week
- Month

But because the enum is stored as a `String`, it will sort in the following order: `Day, Month, Week.`

My naive approach was to add a `Int` property to the enum and sort based on that:

```
extension TestEnum {
    var sortIndex: Int {

        switch self {
        case .Day:
            return 0
        case .Week:
            return 1
        case .Month:
            return 2
        }
    }
}

func < (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {

    return TestEnum(rawValue: lhs.type)?.sortIndex < TestEnum(rawValue: rhs.type)?.sortIndex
}
```

This doesn't work, the comparison function is never called.

What else can I do to sort this in the order I want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Core Data fetch request cannot sort on a computed property, only on persistent stored properties.

If you want your results to be sorted by Core Data, you'll have to change your model to either include a sort order attribute for the enum, or change the enum type from string to number and reorder the enum values.

If you can't or don't want to change your model, you'll have to sort the results *after* they've been fetched, however this would be **very** inefficient (since every object in the results would have to be faulted into memory to compare its enum attribute).

**Update:**

Here's an example of an entity with a `versionOrder` attribute that allows Core Data to sort the versions in a different order from the alphabetic `versionTitle` string.

[image]

You could add a `sortOrder` integer attribute to your model, where .Day = 0, .Week = 1, and .Month = 2, and have Core Data sort the results by that key:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortOrder", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Comment: How exactly do you include a sort order attribute ? Seems that it should be a good solution, but can you tell me more about this approach ?

Comment: @Adrian Added illustration showing a persistent attribute used for sorting in a non-alphanumeric manner.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. You only need to change the `<` function:

```
func < (lhs: TestEnum, rhs: TestEnum) -> Bool {
    return lhs.sortIndex < rhs.sortIndex
}
```

Since you are defining how to compare two `TestEnum` values, you don't need to define how to compare *every* object.

Comment: I tried this also. The functions is never called. I did choose in CoreData to sort by the String field. So maybe it does that automatically, sorts based on strings and never looks at my object that is actually stored in Core Data.

Comment: The default sorting order in Core Data is based on the value of the object. Perhaps you can show what the `sortDescriptor` for your view/Core Data is?

Comment: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "type", ascending: false)]  -- type is my enum field but stored as String inside Core Data

Comment: How about `[NSSortDescriptor(key: "type.sortIndex", ascending: false)] `?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It's not sorting and also I get error when I add data beucase it doesn't know about "sortIndex".

Comment: @Adrian you can always use .hashValue

Comment: @LeoDabus: I am not sure how. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Core Data is going to convert the sort descriptor to a SQLite request. It won't use custom operators, because those don't exist in SQLite.